# Syntax error at or near "FOR" while using "execute format" in a function

Tags: postgresql, loops, stored-procedures, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

This function compiled successfully:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FieldValidations1(tbl_name varchar(35),col_name varchar(25), error_flag varchar(3))
RETURNS void AS $$
declare
    cust_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    execute format($sel$

    FOR cust_rec IN SELECT %I FROM %s 
    LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'inside loop';
    END LOOP;

    $sel$,
    col_name,tbl_name);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But while calling the function,

```
select FieldValidations1('raw_tbl1','col1','gg');
```

the error appears like this

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOR"
LINE 3: FOR cust_rec IN SELECT col1 FROM raw_tbl1
    ^
QUERY:

FOR cust_rec IN SELECT col1 FROM raw_tbl1
LOOP
RAISE NOTICE 'inside loop';
END LOOP;

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "fieldvalidations1" line 6 at EXECUTE statement
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be aware that plpgsql functions are only tested on a superficial syntactical level in `CREATE FUNCTION`. It does not find all possible errors, it does not try to evaluate functions.

Would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION field_validations2(tbl_name text
                                            , col_name text, error_flag text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   cust_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR cust_rec IN
        EXECUTE format('SELECT %I FROM %I', col_name, tbl_name)
    LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'inside loop';
    END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[The proper syntax for a `FOR-IN-EXECUTE` statement can be found in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING)

Also fixed a couple of other things. `text` instead of `varchar(n)` is just a friendly advice.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to `execute` plpgsql. It must be plain SQL.